# Can somebody help me with this assignment on pipes?

Tags: c, pipe

So we have to create a program that creates 3 children processes, which relay information to each other.

- The first process reads in data from a file.
- The second process changes that data by converting the caps on each letter (i.e. lowercase to uppercase and vice-versa).
- The third process writes the information to the file.

My problem is that I cannot seem to get the processes to run by using `fork()` and `waitpid()`. For `waitpid()`, I honestly do not know what belongs in the second and third args. This is my main:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "pipe.c"


int main(void) {

int p, p2, rc, rc2;
rc = _pipe(f_des);
rc2 = _pipe(C1C2);

pid_t pid[3];

pid[0] = fork();
if (pid[0] == 0) {
    puts("create child 1");
    do_child0();
    exit(0);
}
pid[1] = fork();
if (pid[1] == 0) {
    puts("create child 2");
    do_child1();
    exit(0);
}
pid[2] = fork();
if (pid[2] == 0) {
    puts("create child 3");
    do_child2();
    exit(0);
}

waitpid(pid[0], NULL, 0);
waitpid(pid[1], NULL, 0);
waitpid(pid[2], NULL, -1); 
printf("children done, parent goes");

return 0;
}
```

pipe.c:

```
#include "pipe.h"

void do_child1() {

int c, p2;
int rc, rc2;
char *line2, *line3;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
char buffer[80];
//char *line;

close(f_des[1]);
close(C1C2[0]);
printf("Received by child 2 from child 1: ");   

while(k<26) {
for (i = 0; i <= 40; i++) {
    if ((read(f_des[0], buffer, 1)) != '\0') {
//while((rc = read(f_des[0], buffer, 40))) {
    printf("%s", buffer);
    j = 0;
    line2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
    read(f_des[0], buffer, 40);
    line2 = buffer;
    line3 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
    line2 = line3; 

    rc = read(f_des[0], line2, 40);
    printf("%s\n",line2);
    while(j < 40) {
        if(islower(*(line3+j)))
            *(line3+j) = toupper(*(line3+j));
        if(isupper(*(line2+j)))
            *(line3+j) = tolower(*(line3+j));
        }
    rc2 = write(C1C2[1], line3, 40);
    printf("\nLine 3: %s", line3);

    k++;
}
}
}

printf("\n");
close(C1C2[1]);
close(f_des[0]);
exit(0);
}

void do_child2() {
int c;
int rc;
char *line4;

close(C1C2[1]);

while((rc= read(C1C2[0], line4, 40)>0)) {
    line4 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
    printf("%s\n", line4);
}

FILE *file;
file = fopen("C:\\Users\\apkim_000\\Desktop\\newReluctance.c", "a+");
fprintf(file, "%s", line4);
fclose(file);




}



void do_child0() {
FILE *inf = fopen("C:\\MinGW\\bin\\Reluctance.c", "r");
int c;
int rc; 
int i =0;
char buffer[80];
char *line;
cntr = 0;
close(f_des[0]);

printf("From child 1: \n");
while (1) {
    fgets(buffer, 100, inf); //reads in at most 80 char from a line
    if (feof(inf)) //this checks to see if the special EOF was read
        break;     //if so, break out of while and continue with your main
    line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
    line = strtok(buffer, "\n");
    printf("%s\n", line);
    i++;
    cntr++;
    write(f_des[1], buffer, 40);
}
close(f_des[1]);

exit(0);

}
```

pipe.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>


void do_child1();
void do_child2();
void do_child0();

int f_des[2];
int C1C2[2];
int cntr, p3;
```

compiler output:

```
create child 1
From child 1:
Reluctance
OUT through the fields and the woods
And over the walls I have wended;
I have climbed the hills of view
And looked at the world, and descended;
I have come by the highway home, 
And lo, it is ended.
The leaves are all dead on the ground,
Save those that the oak is keeping
To ravel them one by one
And let them go scraping and creeping
Out over the crusted snow,
When others are sleeping.
And the dead leaves lie huddled and still,
No longer blown hither and thither;
The last lone aster is gone;
The flowers of the witch-hazel wither;
The heart is still aching to seek,
But the feet question 'Whither?'
Ah, when to the heart of man
Was it ever less than a treason
To go with the drift of things,
To yield with a grace to reason,
And bow and accept the end
create child 2
Received by child 2 from child 1: RUT through the fields and the woods
create child 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see, but I'm not too confident because its dense code, is that you should be waiting on only the child that will execute longest.  If you don't know which child process that will be, your best bet is to wait on a fifo or have each child create the next child so that the parent only has to wait on one child.

Yeah, have each child do its work, and wait on that child, and when it exits, ahve the main program then start to create the next child.  There's no reason to have them all do this at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Before worrying about `waitpid()`, you should take care of `do_child1()`. The pipe between `do_child0()` and `do_child1()` works, but the line buffer management in `do_child1()` is a mess. `do_child0()` always writes 40 characters per line, while `do_child1()` first reads only 1 character ("R"), then 40 characters (which it discards), and then another 40 characters (starting from the 2nd character of the 2nd line), yielding the output "RUT through the fields and the woods". Then an endless loop `while(j < 40)` is entered; therefore, the program does not proceed.